# How to send key to click Yes button in WebDrive

Tags: selenium-webdriver

When I activate a url via Webdrive that start up a Word Document a dialogbox with a Yes or No  is started up . 
How do I send in keys to click the Yes-button in Webdrive.

Comment: Not enough information. How have you got WebDriver, which is used to automate Web Browsers, talking to MS Word?

Comment: I am using following code to extract the attribute and activating the URL.  for (WebElement e : list) {
   if (value.equals(e.getAttribute("value"))) {
    e.click();
    break;
   }

Answer (score 1):

First you need to switch to the particular window using the following method -

```
WebDriver.switchTo().window()
```

If the name is not known, you can use

```
 WebDriver.getWindowHandles()
```

to obtain a list of known windows. You may pass the handle to

```
switchTo().window().
```

If it's JavaScript you can use -

```
// Get a handle to the open alert, prompt or confirmation
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
// Get the text of the alert or prompt
alert.getText();  
// And acknowledge the alert (equivalent to clicking "OK")
alert.accept();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Since it is not a Browser window I switch to, but a Word Dialogbox in which I have to click the YES button. How do send in a key to press Yes-button.

Comment: If its not a browser then I am sorry Selenium cannot help you in that. You may like to use some desktop application automation tools like QTP or WindowTester!